Using Webform to upload a media file?
I have the Media Module enabled and have a Media type defined called Approved Image.  This is identical to the standard Image but has just one addtional boolean field called 'authorised'.
I can create a Webform that allows type 'Image file' uploads and this works well, but I cannot seem to specify that I want to upload this 'Approved Image' type of file.
What seems to happen is that when an Image file is uploaded, it is in fact a file that is uploaded and not a Media file as such - when you look at Content, you can see them in the File View and that the MIME Type is correctly recorded as, say, image/jpeg.  It is not featured in the Media View.
Is it possible to create a form that allows multiple files of Media types?  I found a module called Webform Content Creator but it only seems to create the first file uploaded as a my Image type.  I am wondering if I am missing something in Webform that allows me to select 'Media' as the file upload type.
Environment: Drupal 10.2.6, PHP 8.1.26, MySQL 8 and Apache.

I'm doing a google, and not seeing any answers for uploading images as media. If I had this requirement, I would probably add a hook on submission that converts the images to media elements. If you don't want the uploaded to be publicly available, the file upload should be set to private.

Thanks @Jaypan I think I have come to that conclusion as well! Just experimenting with using Webform Handlers so I'll see what I can do
